# BST C++ STL implementation, visiting algorithms

Tags: c++, c++11, tree

I am currently learning C++, and as an exercise I tried to implement a BST in a C++11. I am not sure at all if what I have done could be considered a good example of c++ programming, thus I would love to know from you if you believe my code could be improved in terms of functionalities, efficiency, or just programming style.

In particular, these are my doubts:

1. Is the use I made of `unique_ptr` a good idea in this situation? (It should be because of RAII, from what I got.)
2. Is the use of nested class a good idea in this situation, or even in general? In this case I think that maybe it could not be a problem because all its members are public but the class itself is encapsulated within the `BinarySearchTree`, so the inner class is not visible from outside the `BinarySearchTree`class.
3. I am not really sure about the checkBST function. Could it be better?

I had a look at others implementations that I was able to find on the web, in order to correct my first (and I must admit too much C-like first attempt).

```
template<class T> class BinarySearchTree {
private:
    // nested class for the node of the tree
    class TreeNode {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> left;
        std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> right;
        T value;
        TreeNode(T val) {
            value = val;
        }
    };
    // private attributes / methods of BST class
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> root;   // root of the BST
    int V;                            // number of nodes
    void private_recursive_inorderVisit(TreeNode *node) {
        if(node == nullptr)
            return;

        private_inorderVisit(node->left.get());
        std::cout << node->value << std::endl;
        private_inorderVisit(node->right.get());
    }

    void private_iterative_inorderVisit(TreeNode *node) {
        TreeNode *currNode = node;
        std::stack<TreeNode*> s;
        while(s.size() > 0 || currNode != nullptr) {
            if(currNode != nullptr) {
                s.push(currNode);
                currNode = currNode->left.get();
            } else {
                currNode = s.top();
                s.pop();
                std::cout << currNode->value << ", ";
                currNode = currNode->right.get();
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

public:

    BinarySearchTree(const T& RootValue) {
        std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> node(new TreeNode(RootValue));
        root = std::move(node);
        V = 1;
    }

    void insert(const T& newValue) {
        TreeNode* currentNode, *fatherNode;
        currentNode = root.get();
        fatherNode  = nullptr;
        std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> newNode(new TreeNode(newValue));

        while(currentNode != nullptr) {
            fatherNode = currentNode;

            if(newValue < currentNode->value) {
                // insert left
                currentNode = currentNode->left.get();
            } else {
                // inser right
                currentNode = currentNode->right.get();
            }
        }
        if (fatherNode->value > newValue) {
            fatherNode->left = std::move(newNode);
        } else {
            fatherNode->right = std::move(newNode);
        }

        V++;
    }

    void inorderVisit() {
        //private_recursive_inorderVisit(root.get()); // recursive method
        private_iterative_inorderVisit(root.get());
    }

    bool checkBST() {
        TreeNode *currNode = root.get(), *prevNode = root.get();
        std::stack<TreeNode*> s;
        T minVal;
        bool minFound = false;

        while(s.size() > 0 || currNode != nullptr) {
            if(currNode != nullptr) {
                s.push(currNode);
                currNode = currNode->left.get();
                if(currNode == nullptr && !minFound) { // left extreme node. Supposed to be the minimum
                    minVal = s.top()->value; // the parent of the null one is the minimum
                    minFound = true;
                }
            } else {
                // root = predecessor
                prevNode = s.top();
                s.pop();
                currNode = prevNode->right.get();
                if(prevNode->value < minVal || currNode != nullptr && currNode->value < minVal)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    int size() {
        return V;
    }

};




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    BinarySearchTree<int> BST(50);
    BST.insert(15);
    BST.insert(20);
    BST.insert(70);
    BST.insert(3);
    BST.inorderVisit();
    std::cout << "BST checked. Result is " << ((BST.checkBST() == true) ? "positive" : "negative") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is not really worth an anser: Why did you give your private methods the prefix `private_` ? Looks really unnecessary to me. Also these methods use `cout`. You should consider using an `ostream`-parameter (that may, or may not be defaulted to `cout`) instead.

Comment: okay, regarding the  `private_` i think you are right. Actually there is no need to use it. Thank you. And  `ostream` can really be a good idea: I had a look at it and it seems to be a more flexible approach. Anyway, if I can ask you, do you have any further advices on the three small questions I asked? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of things which may help you improve your code:

### Use all of the required `#include`s

This code requires three `#include`s which are missing from the code and are required in order to compile.  They are:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
```

### Use `std::make_unique`

The code currently has this constructor:

```
BinarySearchTree(const T& RootValue) {
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> node(new TreeNode(RootValue));
    root = std::move(node);
    V = 1;
}
```

First, use the more modern initializer style for the constructor, and second, use `make_unique`.  A revised form would look like this:

```
BinarySearchTree(const T& RootValue) :
    root{std::make_unique<TreeNode>(RootValue)},
    V{1}
{}
```

### Don't allow duplicate entries

A binary search tree typically does not allow duplicate keys, but this implementation does not prevent us from adding duplicate values.  To maintain the uniqueness of keys, the code should refuse to allow adding a duplicate.

### Prefer smart pointers to raw pointers

Many places in the code use raw pointers rather than the smart pointers already defined within the program.  As an example, consider this rewrite of `iterative_inorderVisit`:

```
void iterative_inorderVisit(const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *node) const {
    std::stack<const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *> s;
    while(s.size() > 0 || *node) {
        if(*node) {
            s.push(node);
            node = &(*node)->left;
        } else {
            node = s.top();
            s.pop();
            std::cout << (*node)->value << ", ";
            node = &(*node)->left;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Note that `std::unique_ptr<T>::operator bool() const` is defined as returning `true` if there is an underlying object or `false` if `get()` would have returned `nullptr`.  This is used above to simplify the code.  Also, the passed parameter `node` is used within the function -- there is no need to declare and initialize another copy.

### Consider generalizing usage

The `iterative_inorderVisit()` function mentioned above would be more useful if it took a reference to a unary predicate.  That is, instead of hardwiring the printing routine into the function, why not let the user decide what to do for each member?  One could code that like this:

```
void iterative_inorderVisit(const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *node, 
    void (*unaryop)(const T&)) const 
{
    std::stack<const std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *> s;
    while(s.size() > 0 || *node) {
        if(*node) {
            s.push(node);
            node = &(*node)->left;
        } else {
            node = s.top();
            s.pop();
            unaryop((*node)->value);
            node = &(*node)->left;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the public `inorderVisit` looks like this:

```
void inorderVisit(void (*unaryop)(const T&)) const {
    iterative_inorderVisit(&root, unaryop);
}
```

And it is called from `main` like this (in this case with a lambda):

```
BST.inorderVisit([](const std::string &s){ std::cout << s << ", "; });
```

Note that in this particular example, I've chosen to have a `BinarySearchTree<std::string>` instance instead of filling the tree with `int`s.

### Separate member functions into logical parts

The `insert` function actually does two things.  First, it looks through the tree for the passed key, and then it adds the node.  It would probably make more sense to separate those into separate functions.  Here is a suggestion for how one might implement `find`:

```
std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> &find(const T& val) {
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *it = &root;
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        if (val < (*it)->value) {
            if ((*it)->left) {
                it = &(*it)->left;
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        } else if ((*it)->value < val) {
            if ((*it)->right) {
                it = &(*it)->right;
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        } else {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    return *it;
}
```

This `find` returns either a matching `TreeNode` (that is, an existing node which contains the searched-for `val`) or the `TreeNode` that is the last actual node searched before the search failed.  The next thing needed is a function to insert a value at a particular place in the tree:

```
bool insertAt(const T& newValue, std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *here) {
    if (newValue < (*here)->value) {
        auto fresh = std::make_unique<TreeNode>(newValue);
        (*here)->left.swap(fresh);
        ++V;
    } else if ((*here)->value < newValue) {
        auto fresh = std::make_unique<TreeNode>(newValue);
        (*here)->right.swap(fresh);
        ++V;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This uses a single pointer rather than two and also only uses the `<` operator.  This means that only that comparison operator needs to be defined for the `T` type.  Additionally, it returns a boolean value.  Given those, it is very easy to construct an `insert`:

```
bool insert(const T& newValue) {
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> *curr = &find(newValue);
    return insertAt(newValue, curr);
}
```

### Use const where practical

The `size` function does not alter the underlying object and so should be declared `const`:

```
int size() const {
    return V;
}
```

Similarly, `checkBST` could also be `const`.

### Try to improve naming

The size variable `V` is an odd and unintuitive name.  Similarly, `checkBST` is a member function, so the `BST` part of that name is implicit.  Instead, it could be `check` or maybe, `verifySanity`.  As others have mentioned, the `private_` prefix for some of your member functions is not very useful either.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.
some line with text

Answer (score 2):

Okay some minor things here:

As I mentioned in a comment:

### Naming

Why did you give your private methods the prefix `private_` ? Looks code noise to me. Also these methods use `cout`. You should consider using an `ostream`-parameter (that may, or may not be defaulted to cout) instead. This way you could let the caller of the method decide whether he wants the output in a console, or a file, or sent to the international space station.

One of your methods is called `inorderVisit`. Consider calling it `visitInOrder` as method names should generally start with a verb.

### Pointers

Next thing:

```
std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> node(new TreeNode(RootValue));
```

This line of code obviously works, but generally it is recommended to use `make_unique` instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> node = std::make_unique<TreeNode>(RootValue);
```

Also you are mixing `unique_ptr` with raw pointers. Consider using `weak_ptr` or `shared_ptr` where necessary.

### Nested class

I rarely ever use nested classes, but your case here seems like it's worth an exception. This inner class is only used inside the outer class and has no sense whatsoever outside of the class. So making it an inner class seems like the way to go.

Comment: nice. Thank you very much for these advices. So for the pointers i should use weak_ptr for something like `TreeNode *currNode = root.get(), *prevNode = root.get();`. correct?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't mix raw pointers with smart ones.

Also, it's a good idea to use `size_t` isntead of `int` for size, because it'll be more consistent with STL. What's more, you can implement some `iterator`-semantics, it'll benefit your check function too.

Finally, insert-function needs some move semantics too.

Comment: the iterator thing is indeed a good idea! thank you ;)